# why doesn't mkdir -m 07 test use umask?

Tags: permissions, chmod, umask

`umask` returns `0011`. Consequently, when I do `mkdir -m 07 test` I'd expect the resultant directory to have `d------rw-` permissions but it doesn't - it has `d------rwx` permissions.

What's up with this?

Answer (score 3):

That's the intended behaviour, take a look at `man mkdir`:

```
   -m, --mode=MODE
          set file mode (as in chmod), not a=rwx - umask
```